# Solving numbers with multiple constraints

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find integers $a,b,c$ that holds the following properties
$$a\mod{2}=1$$
$$b=a+1$$
$$b\mod{3}=0$$
$$c=b+1$$
$$c\mod{4}=3$$

One such solution satisfying all these constraints is $(a,b,c)=(5,6,7)$. It is known that there exist infinitely many such integer solutions.

Is there a way to determine if such an integer solution exists?

If so, is there a generic way to obtain such solution? The solution should be in the form of a linear equation involving a single variable.

* If there exists **n** variables involving at most **n-1** equations, how to obtain a generic solution? Note that the relation between the variables can be any mathematical operation.

As per my current knowledge, I know that $a$ should take the form $2l+1$, $b$ has the form $3m$ and c has the form $4n+3$ where $l,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But I cannot determine the combined form that all variables have to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You constraints are equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
a \equiv 1 &\pmod 2\\
a \equiv -1 \equiv 2 &\pmod 3\\
a \equiv 1  &\pmod 4.
\end{cases}
$$
This is obtained by substituting $a+1$ for $b$ and $a+2$ for $c$ and simplifying. We see that the first congruence is redundant because $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies $a \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. So the system becomes
\begin{cases}
a \equiv 2 &\pmod 3 \\
a \equiv 1 &\pmod 4.
\end{cases}
Such systems can be solved using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). In your case the general solution is $a\in \{5+12k\mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. So the solution set for $(a,b,c)$ is $\{(5+12k,6+12k,7+12k)\mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

The Chinese Remainder Theorem holds more generally for any number of congruences when the moduli are relatively prime. If they are not relatively prime (as ours were not originally, since $\gcd(2,4)>1$) you can often do some tricks to re-write the system (as we did by noting that the first congruence was implied by the third).

Comment: Does this theorem also hold good if c=a+b? @kccu

Comment: how to solve if c=a+2b @kccu

Comment: @AShanmukhaBruhadroop You can still do the substitution but in the first case (assuming we still have $b=a+1$) you would have $c=2a+1$, and thus $2a+1\equiv 3 \mod 4$, i.e., $2a \equiv 2 \pmod 4$. This implies either $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $a \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, so you'd have to solve those two systems separately. In the second case you'd get $c=3a+2$, so $3a+2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, i.e., $3a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Now $3$ is actually invertible modulo $4$ (its inverse is $3$ since $3 \cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), so this is equivalent to $a \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: or just note the product of coprime mpduli is also their lcm. so CRT generalizes to 1 solution mod any numbers lcm.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

- $a=2h+1 \implies b=2h+2 \implies c=2h+3$

then we need also

- $b=3k$

that is

$$2h+2=3k \implies h=\frac32k-1 \implies k=2j$$

and then

- $a=6j-1, \;b=6j, \; c=6j+1$

then we need also

- $c=4i+3$

that is

$$6j+1=4i+3 \implies i=\frac32 j-\frac12 \implies j=2n+1$$

then finally

- $a=12n+5$
- $b=12n+6$
- $c=12n+7$

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting (eliminating) $\,b,c\,$ in terms of $\,a\,$ then solving for $\,a\,$ by CRT

$\!\bmod 4\!:\,\ 3\equiv c\equiv b\!+\!1\equiv a\!+\!2\iff a\equiv 1\iff \color{#0a0}{a = 1\!+\!4k}$

$\!\bmod 3\!:\,\ 0\equiv b\equiv a\!+\!1\equiv \color{#0a0}{2\!+\!4k}\equiv 2\!+\!k\iff k\equiv 1\iff\color{#c00}{ k = 1\! +\! 3n}$

So $\  \color{#0a0}{a = 1\!+\!4}\,\color{#c00}k = 1\!+\!4(\color{#c00}{1\!+\!3n}) = 5\!+\!12n,\,$ which satisfies $\, a\equiv 1\pmod{\!2}$

**Remark** $ $ The same method works in general. The (here trivial) elimination is a special case of triangularization that occurs in Hermite / Smith normal form algorithms for solving systems of congruences. Search on those terms to learn more about these general methods.